Clarification on the use of 'Exulted' in a sentence from 'Orbital' by Samantha Harvey
I've been reading "Orbital" by Samantha Harvey and came across this sentence, where the tense of the word "exulted" triggered my typo warning:

"The earth is the face of an exulted lover; they watch it sleep and
wake and become lost in its habits."

I've checked the meanings of the verb "to exult," and the past participle doesn't seem to fit with the sentence structure—I would have expected "exulting" or "exalted."
Am I missing something? Is it an archaic construction?
DISCLAIMER: I'm not a native English speaker, and a literal translation of the sentence in my language doesn't make much sense.

I've never heard exult used transitively before.

an exulted-over lover or an exulted-in lover would be grammatical.

"they watch it sleep and wake and become lost in its habits" is hardly an expression of "exultation".   That suggests "an exalted lover".

I'm in tune with your discomfiture, applaud your checking (though you could have said which dictionaries didn't lend support), agree that your error suggestions might apply, and really appreciate your readiness to accept that this might yet be an acceptable peripheral usage. OED should confirm whether 'exulted' can / once was acceptably used as a past-participial adjective.

@TimR Where does the quoted sentence say "they" are exulting? She's saying this of the earth, isn't she? It's a different question that her choice of the word is strange.

@user405662   The word exulted used adjectivally would be formed from the past participle of a (putatitve) transitive verb to exult (someone or something).    There is no explicit statement that "they" are the "exulters", merely the implicit suggestion since the two independent clauses are joined by a semi-colon, indicating that they are more closely related (in some way) than two independent clauses separated by a full stop.  And watching it sleep and getting lost in its habits do suggest the behavior of a lover.

There are intransitive verbs with past participles e.g. gone, fallen, risen, slept. It's not unusual to see "exulted" used in this way, although you can argue whether it's a mistake. Hansard: "I am told that tributes are reserved for more nominally exulted beings." Deadline: "While comedies like the BBC’s Man Like Mobeen were exulted for their authenticity, there is a view that UK drama is the domain of white writers, producers, and directors, and this has damaged representation."

@StuartF  Those seem like malapropisms for exalted.  What is an exulted being?

Please read << whether 'exulted' can be / once was >> for << whether 'exulted' can / once was >> in the comment above..

I wondered whether it should have been "exulting lover", but perhaps it is a lover who has recently exulted.

Based on the context, it should be exalted (elevated, esteemed, glorified). At the very least it would need to be exultant (joyful)—the adjective form of exult:

The earth is the face of an exalted lover; they watch it sleep and
wake and become lost in its habits.The earth is the face of an exultant lover; they watch it sleep and wake and become lost in its habits.

It’s a common error to use exulted where exalted is meant. The Cambridge English Dictionary has this to say about exulted:

Examples of exulted
In English, many past and present participles of verbs can be used as
adjectives. Some of these examples may show the adjective use.

Indeed, two of the seven samples show “the adjective use.” And both are incorrect; exalted is meant here:

Under conditions of greater economic insecurity, the material
dimension of politics assumed an exulted status. I am
told that tributes are reserved for more nominally exulted
beings.

Good thing they have a disclaimer:

These examples are from corpora and from sources on the web. Any
opinions in the examples do not represent the opinion of the Cambridge
Dictionary editors or of Cambridge University Press or its
licensors.

tl;dr: exulted is not an adjective.

I would temper "it should be" with disclaimers about "for standard, everyday use." The fuller context is quite poetic in tone with many non-standard usages ("nine months of this sardine living," sentence fragments, etc.). While modern proofreading seems to let many typos through, my gut says this is an intentional if eccentric usage.
